# Mark all messages as read in GMX webmail

Tags: gmx

How can I select multiple messages and mark them as read in [GMX](http://www.gmx.com/mail)?

Answer (score 1):

You can select all the unread messages by clicking on the arrow of the bar above the list.

Then click on the arrow beside the checkbox and select "Mark as: read".